# Excel VBA: How to determine what textbox or combobox was used last in userform in current runtime?

Tags: excel, variables, combobox, keypress

I have a simple userform and some textboxes and comboboxes there.
I would like to use a variable what store the name or other identification of the text/combobox where in the last keypress happend.
It is required because the following event depend on what text/combobox was used.

The comboboxes and textboxes are generating dinamicaly on the fly based on other sheets headlines so almost every case different.

Comment: Last used but in the current runtime!

Comment: It sounds like you might want to 1) declare some global variable, 2) ensure the dialogs you want to "track" each have an event handler, and 3) have each event handler write to the global variable.

Comment: Ok, but which way can I read out i.e. the name of the dialogs?